# Filesize Error Message

Tags: php, html

I wonder whether someone could please help me.

I'm trying to incorporate an 'filesize' error message into a script, shown below, which is used to upload BLOB files to a mySQL server.

```
if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// This function makes usage of 
// $_GET, $_POST, etc... variables 
// completly safe in SQL queries 
function sql_safe($s) 
{ 
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        $s = stripslashes($s); 

    return mysql_real_escape_string($s); 
} 

// If user pressed submit in one of the forms 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{ 
    if (!isset($_POST["action"])) 
    { 
        // cleaning title field 
        $title = trim(sql_safe($_POST['title'])); 

        if ($title == '') // if title is not set 
            $title = 'No title provided';// use (empty title) string 

            @list(, , $imtype, ) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); 
            // Get image type. 
            // We use @ to omit errors 

            if ($imtype == 3) // cheking image type 
                $ext="png";   // to use it later in HTTP headers 
            elseif ($imtype == 2) 
                $ext="jpeg"; 
            elseif ($imtype == 1) 
                $ext="gif"; 
            else 
                $msg = 'Error: unknown file format'; 
 if($_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/1024000 >= 10) 
            {     
            $fileErrMsg = "<br />Your uploaded file size:<strong>[ ". $_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/1024000  . " MB]</strong> is more than allowed Size.<br />";        
            } 

        if (isset($_FILES['photo'])) 
        { 
            if (!isset($msg)) // If there was no error 
            { 
                $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); 
                $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data); 
                // Preparing data to be used in MySQL query 

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table} 
                                SET ext='$ext', title='$title: ', 
                                    data='$data'"); 

                $msg = 'Success: Image Uploaded'; 
            } 
        } 
        elseif (isset($_GET['title']))      // isset(..title) needed 
            $msg = 'Error: file not loaded';// to make sure we've using 
                                            // upload form, not form 
                                            // for deletion  

        if (isset($_POST['del'])) // If used selected some photo to delete 
        {                         // in 'uploaded images form'; 
            $imageid = intval($_POST['del']); 
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE imageid=$imageid"); 
            $msg = 'Image deleted'; 
        } 

        if (isset($_POST['view'])) // If used selected some photo to delete  
        { // in 'uploaded images form';  
            $imageid = intval($_POST['view']);  
            mysql_query("SELECT ext, data FROM {$table} WHERE imageid=$imageid");  

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)  
            {  
                $image = $row['myimage'];  
                header("Content-type: image/gif"); // or whatever  
                print $image;  
                exit;  
            }  
        }  
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $imageid = intval($_POST['del']); 

        if ($_POST["action"] == "view") 
        { 
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT ext, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(imagetime), data 
                                     FROM {$table} 
                                    WHERE imageid=$imageid LIMIT 1"); 

            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
                die('no image'); 

            list($ext, $imagetime, $data) = mysql_fetch_row($result); 

            $send_304 = false; 
            if (php_sapi_name() == 'apache') { 
                // if our web server is apache 
                // we get check HTTP 
                // If-Modified-Since header 
                // and do not send image 
                // if there is a cached version 

                $ar = apache_request_headers(); 
                if (isset($ar['If-Modified-Since']) && // If-Modified-Since should exists 
                    ($ar['If-Modified-Since'] != '') && // not empty 
                    (strtotime($ar['If-Modified-Since']) >= $imagetime)) // and grater than 
                    $send_304 = true;                                     // imagetime 
            } 

            if ($send_304) 
            { 
                // Sending 304 response to browser 
                // "Browser, your cached version of image is OK 
                // we're not sending anything new to you" 
                header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y', $ts).' GMT', true, 304); 

                exit(); // bye-bye 
            } 

            // outputing HTTP headers 
            header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data)); 
            header("Content-type: image/{$ext}"); 

            // outputing image 
            echo $data; 
            exit(); 
        } 
        else if ($_POST["action"] == "delete") 
        { 
            $imageid = intval($_POST['del']); 
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE imageid=$imageid"); 
            $msg = 'Image deleted'; 
        } 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Through some guidance I received on this site I've been able to come up with the way to check the filesize, which starts at this line:

```
if($_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/1024000 >= 10)
```

but I cannot get the error message to work.

The specific message needs to be activated if the file size is over 1MB. When I try to upload a file greater than this, the file is correctly rejected, but I receive the incorrect error message, 'Error: unknown file format'.

I've tried all number of ways to try to get this to work, but I just get the same incorrect error message.

I would be so grateful if someone could take a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

**SOLUTION**

```
if (isset($_FILES['photo'])) 
{ 
list($width, $height, $imtype, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
// Get image type. 

if ($imtype == 3) 
$ext="png"; // 
elseif ($imtype == 2) 
$ext="jpeg"; 
elseif ($imtype == 1) 
$ext="gif"; 
else 
$msg = 'Error: unknown file format'; 

if($_FILES["photo"]["size"]/102400 >= 1)  {          
$msg = "he file you wish to upload is:<strong>[ ". $_FILES["photo"]["size"]/1024000  . " MB]</strong> is more than allowed Size.";         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all of your other error messages go into a variable called `$msg`. I updated your calculation to be a bit easier:

```
if($_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/102400 >= 1) 
{     
    $msg = "<br />Your uploaded file size:<strong>[ ". $_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/1024000  . " MB]</strong> is more than allowed Size.<br />";        
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. I've tried changing the message variable to match the others in my script, but unfortunately I'm still receiving the incorrect 'file format' error message. Kind regards

Comment: If you are using my code and you're still getting that error message then I suggest echoing the file size you're calculating to verify it's correct: `echo "FILESIZE:".($_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]/102400); exit;` Also, if the 'file format' error messaging is showing you should double check your `$imtype` value

Comment: thanks for this. I must admit to being particularly inexperienced when it comes to PHP, but I'll certainly start to look at your suggestions. Kind regards

Comment: I've just added the echo line and the Filesize is shown as zero. I must admit this has thrown me, because isn't the filesize part of the characteristics of the file retrieved by this line:
@list(, , $imtype, ) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);

Comment: Try using: `list($width, $height, $imtype, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);`.  Don't suppress the errors with `@` and see if it's trying to throw something.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, many thanks for bearing with me on this. I changed the line to your suggestion and I recieved the following: Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/blobtest2.php on line 39. With line 39 being the line I've just added. I hope this helps. Kind regards

Comment: Do a `print_r($_FILES);exit;` on that page. You're using `fileupload` when getting the size of the upload, and then `photo` when you're using `getimagesize`.

Comment: Hi, apologies for not getting back to you sooner. Sincere thanks for the suggestion. I added this to the script and again it confirmed that the filesize was zero. Could you tell me please is this what I should expect? Kind regards

Comment: I suggest posting your HTML Form code for the file upload as well.  I'm assuming you're using the wrong keys when doing all these checks.

Comment: I've been working on this since my last post, and I must have had a typo in the code I added. I am now getting the size of the file following the insertion of 'print' line you suggested. The output of which is:
Array ( [photo] => Array ( [name] => SAM_0376.JPG [type] => image/pjpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpINZtDs [error] => 0 [size] => 1648175 ) ) 
Am I right to assume that my error message now needs to get the variable value from the field called 'size'. Kind regards

Comment: many thnaks for all your help, I've finally got this to work. I worked out that the issue was this line in my form <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000"> Irrespective of the 'value' it seemed to conflict with getting the size of file and hence the error message wasn't created. As sson as I deleted it, the error message worked fine. Sincere thanks for all your time trouble and patience. Kind regards. I've posted the solution in my original post for anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to php but i searched for that and found this in manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

I posted as an answer because i cant comment. i hope it helps.